# 'NestMicroservice' incorrectly implements interface 'INestMicroservice'

Tags: node.js, express, interface, microservices, nest

error TS2420: Class 'NestMicroservice' incorrectly implements interface 'INestMicroservice'.
Property 'listenAsync' is missing in type 'NestMicroservice' but required in type 'INestMicroservice'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply ensure you install the same version of the current `@nestjs/core`.
Ex: If you're currently on NestJS Version 8 (*@nestjs/core -> 8.4.7*)
`pnpm i @nestjs/microservices@8.4.7`

Comment: More like downgrading the Microservices version. And it works fine.
*I just had an exact error now*

Comment: It works. This answer should be accepted.